Bar plots with identical bar width *and* identical bar spacing across *several* plots
Similarly to this question, I want to generate several and separate bar plots that always have the same bar width. That said, I also want that in each of these plots, the spacing between the bars is the same.
I also need these plots to be saved individually, and that each saved image size is proportional to the number of bars. I do not want to use facets or grids (which means similar questions on SO does not apply to me). Furthermore, I need a geom_bar() solution together with ggsave().
REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE
Libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

Mock data (in reality, I have hundreds of variables and up to 15 levels for some factors)
df <- structure(list(Animal = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                          1L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("Cat", "Dog", "Horse"), class = "factor"), 
                     Sex = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Female", 
                                                                                           "Male"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

Function to generate bar plots
# Create counter
counter <- 0

# Function
make_bar_plots <- function(df){ 
  
  # We loop over the columns
  for (col in colnames(df)){ 
    
    # (1) Preparation ##########################################################
    # Store N
    N <- sum(!is.na(df[col]))
    # Store number of levels
    n_levels <- length(unique(df[!is.na(df[col]), col]))[1]
    # Update counter at each iteration
    counter <- counter + 1
    
    # (2) Basic bar plot #######################################################
    # We only plot factors
    if (is.factor(df[[col]])) {
      p <- ggplot(data = df[col] %>% filter(!is.na(df[col])),
                  aes(x=fct_rev(fct_infreq(!!sym(col)))))
      # Compute percents for bars
      p <- p + geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)),
                        width = 0.35*n_levels/3, # We make column width proportional to number of levels!
                        fill = 'black',
                        size = 1.5
      ) 
      
      # (3) Annotations ########################################################
      
      # Add percent as annotation
      p <- p + geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..),
                                                     accuracy = 0.1L),
                             y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..))),
                         stat="count", hjust = -0.1, size=4.2)
      # Add a title
      p <- p + labs(title = paste(col),
                    subtitle = paste0('N = ', format(N, big.mark = ',')
                    ))
      
      # (4) Aesthetics #########################################################
      p <- p + theme_minimal()
      p <- p + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
                     axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                     axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                     axis.text.y = element_text(colour='black', size = 12.5),
                     plot.margin = margin(r=25, l=1, b=0, t=1),
                     plot.title = element_text(size = 16.5),
                     plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12.5),
                     panel.grid = element_blank()
                     )
      # Flip coordinates
      p <- p + coord_flip(clip = 'off')
      
      # (5) Print and export   #################################################
      print(p)
      # Export
      ggsave(paste(counter, '_', col, '.png'), path = 'plots/', 
             bg = 'white'
      )
    } 
  }
}

Output
make_bar_plots(df)



Discussion
We see that bar width is the same in both plots. This was achieved with the argument width = 0.35*n_levels/3 that is included in the function.
That said, the spacing between bars is different for Cat, Dog, and Horse (Plot 1), compared to Male and Female (Plot 2).
What I have tried:

In the ggsave() call, to adjust the height of the generated image using a proportion (e.g., height = 2*n_levels/3). That said, the resulting plots have different bar width, see illustration below.
In the aesthetics part of the function, to adjust aspect ratio (e.g., p + theme(aspect.ratio = 1/4)). This too makes the width of the bars different across plots.
A combination of the above, with the same undesired results.

Illustration when using height = 2*n_levels/3


My 2 questions:

How do we obtain the same spacing between bars across all plots, while also keeping bar width identical across all plots?
Furthermore, how do we save an image whose height will be automatically adjusted to the number of bars? In my example (first two plots of this post), the height of the Sex plot (2 bars) would be smaller than that of the Animal plot (3 bars). Currently, both have the same height.


I'm curious if there's a simpler way to do this, but one way to do this perfectly could be to find the largest plot you'll be making, and then pad out all your other graphs with blank data so they have the same number of categories, and then crop the results using imagemagick. Pretty kludgey, I'm afraid.

A simpler approach could be to adjust your height = 2*n_levels/3 to reflect the fixed size of the header. Might be something like height = header_size + cat_size * n_levels. To do it perfectly would require some magic numbers based on your specific output requirements. I don't think you'd want to change your bar widths in this case, since that will change what share of the axis space they occupy.

I get decent results by setting width = 0.4 (pick your favorite value) in geom_bar and adjusting the plot output to reflect the header height (here "1") and an amount (here "0.5") per level. Tweak to taste, depending on the actual ratio of your header height : category height.
ggsave(paste(counter, '_', col, '.png'), path = 'plots/', 
             height = 1 + 0.5*n_levels,
             bg = 'white'
      )




Many thanks @Jon Spring! This works in most cases indeed. Answer accepted

In stead of setting the width of the bar to a variable, set it to a constant, then set the aspect.ratio in your theme to the number of items (bars) on the y axis divided by some scaling factor. For example:
theme(aspect.ratio = n_levels/5)
    


Thanks, but theme(aspect.ratio), as mentioned in my question, does not produce the desired result.

it works for me, as long I as I also change
#width = 0.35*n_levels/3,
width = .9,

This indeed solves my first question. But not the second one, since with this method, both generated images will have the same size. Again, thank you.
